# ./src/App.js Line 6:19: 'Component' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help please.

```
import React from 'react';

import logo from './logo.svg';

import './App.css';

import Greet from './components/Greet'


class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">

        <Greet/>

      </div>

    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

I am facing this error when I run the code:

**./src/App.js
  Line 6:19:  'Component' is not defined  no-undef**

What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `extends React.Component`

Comment: Hi thanks , but i face another lots of error

Comment: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Your code formatting is broken, please fix. Are you exporting your Greet component from `./components/Greet`?

Answer (score 2):

Because you forget to import `component` from `react`.

> Add this line on top of the program

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```